# How do I declare a pointer to a struct within a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Instead of being an int, I would like prev to be a pointer to another Vertex.  However, I can't declare prev as a VertexPointer because the typedef for VertexPointer comes afterwards.  How should I declare prev?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


//function generates a random float in [0,1]
float rand_float();

//all info for a vertex
typedef struct{
    int key;
    int prev;
    float loc[4];
} Vertex;

//using the pointer
typedef Vertex *VertexPointer;
```

Comment: struct Vertex  *prev;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
typedef struct Vertex{
    int key;
    struct Vertex *prev;
    float loc[4];
} Vertex;
```

Comment: @hannah Oh, I did not realize there is a 15 minutes time restriction to accept answer.